# how to use select element onchange event to fill hidden element

Tags: html, onchange, hidden

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, as I've been pulling my hair out trying to make it work!

I have a form with five select elements like this:

```
 <select name="program1" class="floatCtrl" id="cName" required="required" onchange="document.getElementByID('program1_text').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
    <option value="" selected>  </option>
    <option value="1">  Break Dancing 7/2/2013 $40.00</option>
    <option value="2">  Guitar 7/10/2013 $40.00</option>
    <option value="3">  Drums 7/12/2013 $40.00</option>
    <option value="4">  Drawing 6/19/2013 $78.00</option>
    <option value="5">  Watercolor Painting 6/19/2013 $78.00</option>
    <option value="6">  Kids Art 8/7/2013 $30.00</option>
    <option value="7">  Book Making 6/12/2013 $40.00</option>
    <option value="8">  Writing 6/25/2013 $50.00</option>
    <option value="9">  Dog Obedience 6/5/2013 $45.00</option>
    <option value="10"> Skateboarding 7/30/2013 $40.00</option>
    <option value="11"> Dodgeball 8/7/2013 $5.00</option>
    <option value="12"> Jumprope 8/6/2013 $25.00</option>
    <option value="13"> Swimming 6/2/13 $40.00</option>
    <option value="14"> Games 7/2/2013 $20.00</option>
    <option value="15"> Tennis 1 6/18/2013 $30.00</option>
    <option value="16"> Tennis 2 6/25/2103 $30.00</option>
    <option value="17"> Tennis 3 7/2/2013 $25.00</option>
    <option value="18"> Tennis 4 7/16/2013 $25.00</option>
    <option value="19"> Tennis 5 7/23/2013 $35.00</option>
    <option value="20"> Tumbling 5/23/2013 $25.00</option>
    <option value="21"> Backyard Discovery 7/20/2013 $5.00</option>
    <option value="22"> Applegate Discovery 7/27/2013 $10.00</option>
    <option value="23"> Mountain Adventure 8/3/2013 $10.00</option>                                                 
</select>
```

and a hidden input for each one like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="program1_text" id="program1_text" value="" />
```

I'm trying to fill the value of the hidden element "program1_text" with the text from the selected option with the onchage event of the select element "program1". I have researched a lot and this solution is one that I keep coming across, but I just can't get it to work. Can anyone see any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **getElementByID** with **getElementById**. Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: Thank You Very Much Fabi! One of those situations where you know something should work, but it doesn't. You look over it a million times and don't see the mistake that's been staring you in the face for hours!

Comment: YW! it happens to all of us :) Please accept my answer so I can build some reputation as I would like to be more active on here.. :)

btw, the Web Developer add-on and Firebug are great allies for situations like that